# How can I stop the WCF test client from opening when I start debugging?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I realize that I can just make sure I don't have the service open in my active window when I start debugging, but that's a little annoying.  It seems like there's got to be some setting in VS2010 somewhere to turn this off.

For anyone who asks "why would you want to turn it off?", it's because the service is using both SOAP and ReST.  I test ReST in browser or in Fiddler and test SOAP in SOAPUI, and really don't have a need for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is particularly frustrating. I am running VS2010, and cannot locate Properties/Debug tab as most posts reference. However, if you

1. Right-click **Unload Project**
2. Right-click **Edit**
3. Find `EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue` and set its value to `False`

   ```
   <EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>
     False
   </EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>
   ```
4. Save, and right-click **Reload Project**

Should work.

Not sure why this version of VS2010 does not display Debug tab.

Comment: This works for me.  Mine doesn't have a debug tab either, as the other answer indicates.  Might just be a difference in VS versions.

Comment: I'd just like to clarify the first two steps, as contextually I couldn't immediately determine whether this answer was talking about the WCF Test app or the VS2010 IDE. So: in the VS2010 IDE, in Solution Explorer, right-click the project and select 'Unload Project' from the context menu. Then right-click the project again and select 'Edit <projectname>.csproj'. Then do Step 3 as above, then save the change and close the editor window. Then right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select 'Reload Project'.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This has been driving me mad!

Comment: I also could never find the appropriate Debug tab in my version of VS2010.  Thanks this... a few hours saved, I think.

Answer (score 6):

Select `Menu-><Project Name> Properties`.

In the properties window, click on the "Debug" tab in the left hand column.  In the Start Options section in the Command Line Arguments box, you should see the following:

```
/client:"WcfTestClient.exe"
```

Remove that and save the changes.

You might want to also uncheck the "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution" checkbox in the WCF Options tab.

Comment: For me this was the correct answer. Totally nailed the right answer - including the secondary answer/detail about unchecking the option in the WCF options tab. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web site project(VS2010) right click project. Select Properties Window(F4). You should see a property grid of the properties window. There choose False for Always start when debugging. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS2015 and I faced the similar problem. I tried the below steps and it is resolved.
1,Right-Click the project properties
2,Go to Web tab
3,Check the option Current page is selected. If not selected then select it.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2019 this has moved to the <Project_name>.User project file that holds user's preferences are usually outside of source control.

Answer (score 0):

For me, in VS2022, not having the `.svc` or `.svc.cs` containing the service logic opened in the editor was enough to prevent the WCF Test Client from opening when I run the solution.