# WCF Project overriding

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, visual-studio

When I launch my vs projects I build and launch my WCF and my WPF but when I launch a second instance debug running at the same time to have multiple clients attached to the WCF at the same time it clears all the data already in there. I have tried using a `mutex` to make it not run the WCF if it is already running but when I put break points in I realised it was never being hit. Is there a way to change the properties of a vs build so it only runs the project if it isn't already running visual studio 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ussually uncheck this option when I run my WCF manually and debugging

[image]

Comment: Is that in vs2013 as i can't find that tab

Comment: i am using vs 2012, if you cant find it try the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058522/how-can-i-stop-the-wcf-test-client-from-opening-when-i-start-debugging